# Disable Checkboxes in JStree JQUery plugin

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a jstree JQuery pluguin that I use with its "checkbox" plugin. I need to select checkbox programmatically and disable checkboxes, also programmatically.

How I can do that?

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jstree/wLokkEg3eCY%5B1-25%5D this I tried ind got no result.

My Jstree:

```
 var myTree = $(tree).jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "ajax": {
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            "url": urlTree,
            // data: '{"longnames":"' + flag + '"}',

            data: function (n) {
                id = n.attr ? n.attr("id") : prefix + '0';
                reply = '{ id: "' + id + '"';
                //  if (dataJSON.length > 0) {
                //      reply = reply + ", " + dataJSON;
                //  }
                reply += ', longnames: "' + flag + '"';
                // reply += ", prefix: ";
                //  reply += (mutateIds != 1) ? '' : '"' + prefix + '"';
                reply += "}";

                return reply
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {

                return msg.d.data;
            },
            error: function () {
                // process error of ajax
                return false;
            }
        },
        //  "xsl": "flat",


    },
    "search": {
        "show_only_matches": true,
        "search_method": "jstree_contains"
    },
    "types": {
        "max_children": -2,
        "max_depth": -2,
        "default": {
            "valid_children": ["default"],
            "select_node": function (e) {
                this.toggle_node(e);
                return false;
            } 
        },
        "disabled" : { 
                  "check_node" : false, 
                  "uncheck_node" : false 
                }  
    },
    "cookies": {
        "save_opened": false
    },
    "checkbox":{
         "override_ui": "true",
        "real_checkboxes": "true"
    },
    "plugins": pluginsToUse
})
```

Comment: have you tried both suggestions? like adding the function under "defualt"? You would have just to call them afterwards... do you get any js errors in the console after calling the function then?

Comment: Yes I did, basically I added false as result of such functions. I indeed got "rev=disabled" in the LI tags that represent menu items, but it did not changed the behaviour.

Comment: Yeah you could make css class "Hidden" and add and remove it with your own click handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the node programmaticlly all you need to do is:

```
$('#tree').jstree('check_node','#id');
```

Here #id is the id of the node.